# Find Count of racers from Race Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL,I have two tables RACER and SPONSOR, 
RACER TABLE has these columns

```
RACER_NAME,
SPONSOR_ID
RACER_ID- Primary KEY

SPONSOR table has these columns

SPONSOR_ID,
SPONSOR_NAME
```

now I want to find the SPONSOR name and no.of racer associated with that SPONSOR.

Here is what I tried:

```
select s.sponsor_name , (select count(*) from racer r) where INNER JOIN s.sponsor_id = r.sponsor_id
```

Comment: why can't you use `JOIN` by following some tutorials ?

Comment: tried but not getting how to get total no of racers?

Comment: Then, post what you tried

Comment: select s.sponsor_name , (select count(*) from racer r) where INNER JOIN s.sponsor_id = r.sponsor_id

Comment: post it as part of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand, how `JOIN` works and its syntax.

```
select s.sponsor_name, count(*) as total_racer 
from
racer r inner join sponsor s
on r.sponsor_id=s.sponsor_id
group by r.sponsor_id
```

You need to specify both tables in `FROM` clause, which you were missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join ( left join if not al the sponsor have racer ) and get the result without subselect using group by and count

```
  select s.sponsor_name ,  count(*) 
  from SPONSOR s r
  left  JOIN  racer r s.sponsor_id = r.sponsor_id
  GROUP BY s.sponsor_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version, with a subquery is reasonable, particularly because in MySQL it can have better performance than the corresponding `GROUP BY` query.  However, it needs to be a *correlated* subquery.  That looks like:

```
select s.*,
       (select count(*)
        from racer r
        where  s.sponsor_id = r.sponsor_id
       ) as cnt
from sponsor s;
```

In other words, choose either the `JOIN` method or the subquery method, but not both for the same value.